# How to debug "Unable to load GDAL library" error in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2

I have a problem with r.surf.contour. I create a DTM with v.to.rast.attribute and then use the r.surf.contour and it works fine in QGIS 1.9 but with QGIS 2.0 doesn't work.

I have a contour shapefile with elevation values. I use the v.to.rast.attr to rasterize the contour, but some pixels have null values, so I try to use the r.surf.contour to obtain a surface but in the end I've got an error. This is an excerpt: GRASS_INFO_ERROR(3016,1): Unable to load GDAL library GRASS_INFO_END(3016,1) C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin>g.region rast=output91bad3077faa4aa784bcedb42867ff89 And then GRASS_INFO_ERROR(1012,1): Raster map not found.

I think the problem is in raster from grass. Because I try to create a slope map with r.slope.aspect and it give me the same error. Please could you help me? My windows is Windows vista.

Comment: Could you please tell us *how* it fails to work?

Comment: You after that you could raise a bug here: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/sextante/issues

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have a contour shapefile with elevation values. I use the v.to.rast.attr to rasterize the contour, but some pixels have null values, so I try to use the r.surf.contour to obtain a surface but in the end I've got an error. This is an excerpt: GRASS_INFO_ERROR(3016,1): Unable to load GDAL library 
GRASS_INFO_END(3016,1) 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\bin>g.region rast=output91bad3077faa4aa784bcedb42867ff89 
And then GRASS_INFO_ERROR(1012,1): Raster map not found.

Comment: I think the problem is in raster from grass. Because I try to create a slope map with r.slope.aspect and it give me the same error. Please could you help me? My windows is Windows vista.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Sextante and if you have errors you must first look the sextante log file in Yourpath/.qgis2/processing/**processing_qgis.log**. Generally, error messages are explained  more clearly.

In your case, the error:

> Unable to load GDAL library GRASS_INFO_END(...

means "It was not possible to load GDAL library" and as a consequence GRASS cannot load the raster file -> GRASS_INFO_ERROR(1012,1): Raster map not found.

So,

1. it is a problem of configuration in sextante/processing Settings (fix the GDAL path)
2. it is the result of a known bug with the  Windows 2.0 standalone installer : [QGIS 2.0 Win standalone busted](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-2-0-Win-standalone-busted-td5078946.html) -> you have to wait for a new version of the Windows 2.0 standalone installer (with corrections) or use the 1.9 version.

and look in the  [QGIS devoloper list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Quantum-GIS-Developer-f4099106.html) or the [QGIS user list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Quantum-GIS-User-f4125267.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But where do I fix the GDAL path? In processing Options and configuration, I just have a check box for activate. Nothing else.

Comment: in GDALTools parameters, Raster menu

Comment: I have a lot of paths. Which one I have to fix: executables, python modules or help path? I have another two paths: data path and driver path but they are locked. All these paths are indefined. How I fix that?